# Adding body of call to POST using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I am trying to use HTTPURLConnection make a POST method call to a server api. The JSON version of the body of my call is:

```
{
    "grant_type"        : "password",
    "username"          : "perry.marange@zmod.co",
    "password"          : "password"
}
```

How do I add this part using httpURLConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can use the [Android Rest-Client](https://github.com/TylerSmithNet/RESTclient-Android) for sending data to a webservice

take classes `RequestMethod.java` and `RestClient.java` from this link https://github.com/TylerSmithNet/RESTclient-Android/tree/master/RESTclient-example/src/com/tylersmith/restclient

and use those in your project like this

```
String webServiceUrl = "your-service-url";
RestClient client = new RestClient(webServiceUrl);
String serverResponse = "";
String inputJsonString = "{" + 
    "    \"grant_type\"        : \"password\"," + 
    "    \"username\"          : \"perry.marange@zmod.co\"," + 
    "    \"password\"          : \"password\"" + 
    "}";
client.setJSONString(inputJsonString);
client.addHeader("Content-Type", "appication/json"); // if required
try {
    client.execute(RequestMethod.POST);
    if (client.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        // response error
    }
    else
    {
                    // the response from server
        serverResponse = client.getResponse();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle error
}
```