# Android Rest client to Delphi XE2 Datasnap Rest server

Tags: android, delphi, rest, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I found many examples on Stack Overflow and I just don't know where to start since I have a particular prerequisite:

My Delphi Datasnap Rest server is using `ZLibCompression` and RSA encryption (in `TTransportFilterCollection` of `DSHTTPWebDispatcher`). Is there an Android restful API that can handle those? Any sample that already implements that?

I found this thread [Android REST client, Sample?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267928/android-rest-client-sample) as a good starting point, both lightweight and well-formed clients are presented but is it enough for me?

Thanks in advance for any hint, sample or library that you could point me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used the proxy generator from Danasnap server `TDSProxyGenerator` component (`http://yourserver:port/proxy/java_android.zip`) and added this code to my android project...

I had to search for the `DSRESTSSLFactory.java` file that is not generated by the proxy (but required !!), i found it in a demo from embarcadero, and from that point the communication is entirely handled, all accessible procedures are publicated, and really really simple to use...

Comment: Hi, I'm a user of the DataSnap proxy for Android too and I just wondered how you are getting on with it?  I've had some connecticty issues with SSL connections - have you had any problems here?  I'm connecting to a DataSnap server built as a Windows service.  Jonathan

Comment: sorry but i dropped the certificates, too heavy in my case. But post a new Question, you'll get more help than from a comment...

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [Android Rest-Client](https://github.com/TylerSmithNet/RESTclient-Android) for sending data to a webservice

see my answer in the post [Adding body of call to POST using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326289/adding-body-of-call-to-post-using-httpurlconnection/11326578#11326578)